# IQueryable extension method compile error from Generic method

Tags: c#, generics, iqueryable

IQueryable extension method is fine in normal method, but not within a generic method.

Compile error: **IQueryable does not contain a definition for MyExtension and the best extension method overload DataExtensions.MyExtension(IQueryable Fred) requires a receiver of type IQueryable Fred**

*Goal is turn the `// do something interesting` below into a generic method that would work acrross all `FlintstoneObject` types.*

```
public static class RepetitiveCodeBelow
{
    public static int RepetitiveCode()
    {
        var count = 0;
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            foreach (var data in context.Freds.AsNoTracking().Where(item => item.PrimaryKey > 0).MyExtension())
            {
                // do something interesting
            }

            foreach (var data in context.Barnies.AsNoTracking().Where(item => item.PrimaryKey > 0).MyExtension())
            {
                // do something interesting
            }

            // more types omitted
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Working version:

```
    public List<Fred> GetFredList()
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            return context.Freds.AsNoTracking().MyExtension().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Wont compile:

```
    public List<T> GetList<T>() where T : FlintstoneObject<T>, new()
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            return context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().MyExtension().ToList();
        }
    }
```

**Full sample**

```
public abstract class FlintstoneObject<T> where T : class
{
    public abstract int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

public class Fred : FlintstoneObject<Fred>
{
    public override int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

public class Barny : FlintstoneObject<Barny>
{
    public override int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Fred> MyExtension(this IQueryable<Fred> queryable)
    {
        return queryable;
    }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Fred> Freds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Barny> Barnies { get; set; }

    public List<Fred> GetFredList()
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            return context.Freds.AsNoTracking().MyExtension().ToList();
        }
    }

    public List<T> GetList<T>() where T : FlintstoneObject<T>, new()
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            return context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().MyExtension().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception message is self explanatory. Based on you current version of the extension method it will only work on `IQueriable<Fred>`. What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: The error seems reasonably clear to me. Your extension method is valid only for an expression having the type `IQueryable<Fred>`. But in your generic method, the only thing the compiler can prove is that the type is `IQueryable<T>` where `T : FlintstoneObject<T>`. That's not good enough to call a method that requires `IQueryable<Fred>`. There are possible alternatives that would compile. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough context to know which, if any, of those options would work for your case.

Comment: My goal is consolidate into 1 method, a number of snippets which are nearly identical, the difference being the type being handled: Fred, Barny, etc.

Comment: I will add a sample above where each type has  **// do something interesting** which is very repetitive code that is duplicated for a number of data types.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably lacking of this extension:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> MyExtension<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
    {
        return queryable;
    }
```

to make it compilable.

Anyway, what you intended to do with your generic stuff looks strange:

```
public class Fred : FlintstoneObject<Fred>
```

I thought `T` should be some class other than `Fred` which is inheriting the generic type `FlintstoneObject<T>`.

Comment: That is not what I want.  Having that method means I have to check T against known types and call the appropriate specialized function.